# Expected numbers of friendships broken up

Tags: probability

According to the problem, there are N people on Facebook and M friendships made. (Assuming $M \le N(N+1)/2$) since there are only so many possible groups of 2 people being friends. Then, each person in Facebook is assigned a team (read with probability $p$ and blue with probability $(1-p)$. Finally, every friendship with people from different groups is broken up. What is the expected number of friendships broken up?

To be honest, I do not really know how to start this problem. I am not looking for a solution, just something to start with. Requesting help.

Comment: @AlexR. You really just need to know that there are $M$ friendships.  Nothing in the problem indicates that $M$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: By linearity of expectation, it suffices add up, for each friendship, the probability that that friendship is broken up.